# Explicit IEnumerator<T> implementation VS yield return implementation

Tags: c#, .net, ienumerable, yield-return, ienumerator

I have following problem:

I want to implement my own collection, which will also implement `ICollection<T>` interface. That means that I also need to implement `IEnumerable<T>` interface. Implementing `IEnumerable<T>` can be done two ways:

**First approach:** by having private struct implementing `IEnumerator<T>` and returning it from `GetEnumerator()` method

**Second approach:** I can just use iterator (using `yield return`) and let compiler generate `IEnumerator` class for me.

I also want my enumerators to throw `InvalidOperationException` on any `MoveNext()` (or `Reset()`) call after the collection was modified 
[as it is specified in MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.movenext(v=vs.110).aspx)

If I will use **first approach**, then everything is ok (I just save version of my collection when creating new enumerator and then in `MoveNext()` I just check if it hasnt changed). 
The same trick is used by [MS Collections](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/queue.cs,96169fd60b66ca0c) But here is **THE PROBLEM** - if I will use **second approach** I think I cannot enforce following behaviour. Consider following code.

```cs
class MyCollection : ICollcetion<T>
{
int _version = 0;
T[] _collectionData;
public void Modify()
  {
    ... // do the modification
    _version++; // change version, so enumerators can check that they are invalid
  }

...

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
  {
    int _enmVersion = _version;
    int i = 0;
    yield return _collectionData[i];
    if( _enmVersion != _version ) // check if there was not modificaction
    {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
  }

...

}

...

var collection = new MyCollection(); 
var e = collection.GetEnumerator(); 
myCollection.Modfiy(); //collection modification, so e becomes irrecoverably invalidated
e.MoveNext(); // right now I want to throw exception
              //but instead of that, code until first yield return executed
              //and the version is saved... :(
```

This problem occurs only if the collection is modified after obataining enumerator object, but **before first** call to `MoveNext()`, but still it is problem...

My question is: is it possible somehow use **second approach** AND enforce right behaviour OR I need for this case to stick with **first approach** ?

My suspicion is that I have to use **first approach**, since the code of iterator method is exeuted only when I call `MoveNext()` , and not in constructor of compiler generated class, but I want to be sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that an iterator method won't run any code at all until the first `MoveNext()` call.

You can work around this problem by wrapping the iterator in a non-iterator method that grabs the version immediately and passes it as a parameter:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    return GetRealEnumerator(_version);
}

private IEnumerator<T> GetRealEnumerator(int baseVersion) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it does work. I thought that the iterator method signature needs to be GetEnumerator() to be noticed by the compiler.

Comment: No; any method can be an iterator.  Iterators can also return `IEnumerable<T>`.